# Keep society working, when apocalypse is imminent

Tags: society, politics, apocalypse

Here is the deal. Earth will be destroyed and there is no way to stop it. We have about 30 years left. Government is keeping it secret, of course. The good news is, scientists have figured out a feasible way to survive in space for some time (and possibly relocate to other planets), and there are already plans to build a fleet of spaceships just in time. The bad news is, this fleet will only save a **few thousand people**, while building and launching it will require cooperation of every country, every industry, even general public.

Basically, this project is so huge, it cannot succeed being kept secret.

**How to handle this situation?** We need people to know about their almost certain death and at the same time, avoid mass panic and social disintegration, so that people keep working (not rioting "too much").

*One thing that comes to mind would be choosing the few "survivors" randomly just moments before launch when all the work is already done, so everybody gets the same chance. I do not think, this would work too 
well, because people would probably think one in a million chance is not worth it. Also, they might think the government lies (which would most definitely be true, because you can not fly a starship with a bunch 
of random vagabonds, or colonize planets with old people)*

Any thoughts?

Notes:

- By "government" I mean global government all other governments are subject to
- This takes place in near future (2050-ish)
- Earh is getting **destroyed**, not just made uninhabitable. There will be no Earth to live on or orbit

Comment: This is straight up idea generation for now. There is a sandbox in the meta where people help you ask questions. Here are some things where the question is overly broad: a) one would have to look at each country or region separately b) it depends on who ends up at those ships (for example journalists or rich businessmen will make a huge difference). c) every country (and every industry??) is cooperating? That is just not believable. In what way are they cooperating and contributing? The list just starts there and I might be able to get through the entire alphabet, but I'm out of characters.

Comment: The title reminds me of some real-life locations on earth right now

Comment: You've actually written the premise of Seveneves by Neal Stephenson.

Comment: "...people would probably think one in a million chance is not worth it." --> One has clearly never looked at the [odds of winning the lottery](https://www.thebalance.com/what-are-the-odds-of-winning-the-lottery-3306232).

Comment: @Frostfyre Well, lottery does not kill you, when you lose.

Comment: You automatically lose if you don't try. I fail to see why anyone who wanted to live wouldn't make an effort.

Comment: Because you work and get nothing out of it. No retirement, only death. Not working is just more comfortable.

Comment: Maybe just if you work hard and do your job well, you get your name put in a hat to leave?

Comment: The film _"When worlds collide"_ was **exactly** this scenario. Worth watching.

Comment: @Frostfyre: people already offered evidence that can act on a totally illogic ways. Moreover, in this situation you can fail if even 1%(or less) of the population don't collaborate, there are way too much options to destroy all the work by a small group of people.

Comment: Your expectation that the earth will collaborate is pretty funny. More likely people would just be in denial and make counter science think tanks that deny all your research and put most government in no position to commit. At the end of the 30 years, next to no action would have been taken by most countries. 30 years is a long time and in most democratic countries, the government can't stay in power long even for it to even matter, any problem that needs more than 1 term of government to be solved is someone else's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should have faith in people. Humans are capable of killing, stealing, lying, and many other bad things. But at the same time, they are capable of compassion, altruism, and self-sacrifice.

Building Arks would, indeed, require a joint effort of the entire humanity. If you keep the project a secret it would not be possible to maximise this effort. Even if you manage to maintain secrecy for 30 years, enough information would leak to damage the trust between peoples and their governments. The collaboration between nations would be severely impeded, as well. As a result, you would save fewer people than you potentially could.

Thirty years is a long time. Even if you get some panic and suicide waves in the beginning, most likely the humanity would come round and start working on saving the future. Mass panic and breakdown of society in the aftermath of catastrophes are a myth. The majority of people choose to cooperate. There is a lot of research on this topic, you can easily google for specific examples.

I think that you could do several things:

1. Address all nations and tell them the truth.
2. Put **all** cards on the table (no secrets, no double-crossing) and establish an alliance with all nations that have space technologies. Try to get on board everybody else.
3. Start a massive 30-year long propaganda campaign (something similar to the WWII war effort campaigns).
4. Enact martial law if necessary. If possible (and plausible) establish a benevolent authoritarian regime (they are good for getting things done in a short time).
5. Revoke all patents and give open access to all scientific data.
6. Start manufacturing amphetamines (loads and loads of them).
7. Start building DNA database of the entire Earth population.
8. Divert all resources to building ships, space habitats, etc. Stockpile as much as possible. Make sure it is well-protected.
9. Task scientists and engineers with planning an escape. Don't forget to abolish all restrictions, including ethical, on experiments (but do not let it spiral out of control completely, the survivors will be dealing with the survivor syndrome, they do not need to feel additional responsibility for obviously unethical experiments).
10. Switch to three shifts a day (8 hours each). Start distributing amphetamines to all workers (keep scientists off drugs, though).
11. Five years prior to launch choose survivors based on their skills and genetics. Start to train them for survival in space (or a new planet). Make sure the curriculum focuses on practical skills. Everything else can be uploaded into spacecraft computers.
12. Publicly shame and prosecute people who try to interfere with or sabotage the Ark project. At the same time, try to avoid forcing people to work. The general population must believe in the project and **want** it to succeed.
13. Treat the entire thing as a war effort. Emphasise the survival rather than inevitable death. It is a war that humanity can win but at a great cost.

I guess the way I see it, you have to trust humanity to do the right thing. And if it does not, it well deserves extinction.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume we need people to know? Because they don't. You don't tell them shat. This is like "using people 101". Remember Ender's Game? SPOILER:

> It wasn't a game.

"*Hello, I'm Elon Musk and I'm working on a rocket that will go to Mars. Care to join the endeavour? You can also sing on a travel list and maybe you will be the lucky winner of a golden ticket.*"

"*Hello, I'm Elon Musk and I'd like to invite your corporation/country to join the building rockets and colonies on Mars.*"

Also, every smartphone is actually part of a cluster that is making necessary calculations. As are students that are doing complicated ones by hand.

You need thousand of guinea pigs for testing rocket fuels? Well, why not drive the new TeZla model Pi or the hydrogen Hunday.

Those people are dead already, you don't owe them nothing.

Comment: Because this is just too big. It will require shifting a lot of resources from where they are not so critical. Shoud I just tell people: "We are stopping development of a new iPhone, because Elon Musk wants his spaceships" ?

Comment: @J.Joscak In what way are iPhone developers connected to your spaceship? If every human being has to become a slave and start building some spaceship parts, society has already stopped working.

Comment: They are connected, because they have engineers, cutting edge tech and lot of man-hours we need for spaceships.

Comment: @J.Joscak Ok, shifting resources. You know what killed corset? War need for steel. You need oil to run machinery? Convince people to use electric cars. Rise prices. Put bans on high emission. And what's the difference for engineer to work on a computer or to work on a computer? iPhones are the things we need for ship and people are PAYING to test them. You create slaves because what you pay them for work they spend at your company store.

Comment: There's no reason to tell people you stopped developing the iPhone, or anything else for that matter. A lot of the technology we have now was originally developed for military use, and was top secret until it landed in our collective pockets.

Worst case scenario, you can release the same iPhone for the next 30 years, but as long as you repackage it right and make it a little rounder on the edges, no one will know it's just the iPhone X for the tenth time.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY: because in reality you cannot keep a secret like this for over 30 years and at the same time ask for collaboration from, basically, at least a couple billion people.

Comment: @Gianluca Yeah, that's the thing. You don't ask. You manipulate them into helping you out. You create a lab maze. In other words can you prove that what Musk is doing is not because Earth will be destroyed? electric cars, self landing rockets and fast travel build with minimum sources. Look like plans to establish base on Mars for me.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY which is what Musk always said. But with Musk we are talking about 3 or 4 companies. In this scenario you are basically shifting the production of Earth toward something else. And in real life, a catastrophe like the complete destruction of Earth does not happen in a day, so no, you can manipulate 2 billion people for some time, but you will no be able to cover the truth all this time.

Comment: @Gianluca With Musk it's only Musk "believing" the end of earth. If you show all those fat politicians data on some star exploding guess who will wan to go on the ships first? And they are practiced in fooling and lying to people to get what they want. "Funk the people, Kim Jong Un is my new best friend, but I will say we both need better nuclear arsenal and more rockets because we are twittenemies"

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY If you can hide the star exploding data (or whatever else is the cause) you can probably at least begin. But such data will be revelead. And since we are talking about years, no doubt that you will fail.

Answer (score 0):

several reasons

Denial, many people just won't face their own mortality. This is the same reason young people don't buy health insurance or create retirement funds.

Hope, your lottery helps a lot, people are willing to bet on longshots all the time especially with no alternative.

Familiarity, some people cope with tragedy by retreating to familiarity, this ties in tightly with denial.